# Showing a function is harmonic on a domain - Imaginary part of $(A\cosh(z)+\frac\pi z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

How to know that $\text{Im}(A\cosh(z)+\frac\pi z)$ is harmonic on domain $\{z|0\lt\text{Im }z\lt \pi\}$ where $A\in\Bbb R$?

I am not sure how I would verify Laplace's equation here(which I imagine is how I am meant to solve this).

I tried reducing it to it's imaginary components, but it seemed to be the wrong method.

Comment: As best I can tell at least, it's the imaginary part of a holomorphic function on the given domain. (Note that the given domain does not include $0$.) Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: @Ian So since it is the imaginary part of a holomorphic function it is harmonic?

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic, yes. This follows by a straightforward calculation with the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @Ian Wow, I have no idea how I didn't know this... That is embarrassing. All I knew was that after finding the harmonic conjugate of some $u$ or $v$ you obtain a holomorphic function $u+iv$. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's an answer (since I could not find it written anywhere yet).

*The real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function are harmonic.*

Proof: Suppose $f = u+iv$ is holomorphic ($u,v$ real). The Cauchy-Riemann equations say $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. Therefore, 
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=v_{yx}-v_{xy}=0$$
and 
$$v_{xx}+v_{yy}=-u_{yx}+u_{xy}=0$$
as claimed.